# Tourist Visa to Israel for Indian Students studying in the US

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, israel

I have to travel to Israel for a short trip on my Indian Visa. I'm currently studying in the US on an F-1 Visa. I read that I need a tourist visa to travel to Israel. What are the steps I need to take to get one ?

Do I need to make a trip to the Israel Embassy ?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, at least you need to double check the current visa situation with the embassy through the phone**.

If you are from an Asian nation, it is the best to contact the embassy regarding your trip. Israel rightfully so, takes their country's security very very seriously.

**Additional Note**: Also, you need to choose your destination wisely and don't do anything stupid (e.g., going to the conflict zone and start taking pictures) while you are there; or you might confused the forces, and you get shot at right in there, as they might think you are there to join the 72 virgins.

Comment: `join the 72 virgins` Well I laughed, but it might be offensive for some persons on this forum. Not everybody has a taste for all types of humour.

Comment: @DumbCoder Actually this is something that came from hard liners' philosophy, and not a whole religion. Anyhow enjoying my freedom of speech ;-)